# Why is this query using the index differently when i change the range of search?

Tags: mysql, date, indexing, date-range, clustered-index

I have a question about indexing and a strange (I suppose) behaviour I found when trying out some queries I'm using in a project.
I have the following schema:
a) an `activities` table

```
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field   | Type                                                   | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id      | bigint unsigned                                        | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| date    | timestamp                                              | NO   | UNI | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| address | varchar(255)                                           | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| title   | varchar(255)                                           | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| state   | enum('todo','done','interrupted','pending','rejected') | NO   |     | todo              |                   |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

b) a `users` table

```
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id                | varchar(128)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                   |
| email             | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| name              | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| surname           | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| phone_number      | varchar(1024) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| propic_url        | varchar(500)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                  +
```

c) and a `worker_to_activity` table to assign workers to a specified activity

```
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| activity_id | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| worker_id   | varchar(128)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have a very simple query that searches for all the activities in a certain time range in which a specified user is present, something like this:

```
select 
a.date
a.id,
a.address,
a.title,
a.state
    from activities a
where a.date >= "start" and a.date <= "end"
and exists ( select worker_id from worker_to_activity where worker_id = "worker_id" and activity_id = a.id ) 
limit 11;
```

And, last but not least, I have an index for this purpose:

```
create index act_fetch_idx (date, id, address, title, state) on activities;
```

For testing purposes (seeing if the index works) I deliberately inserted an activity that happens before other activities, but with an higher ID, simulating somebody inserting an activity later than expected (I'm talking about activity #50 in the following view):

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2022-09-14 08:00:00 |
|  2 | 2022-09-14 09:00:00 |
|  3 | 2022-09-14 10:00:00 |
| 50 | 2022-09-14 10:55:49 |
|  4 | 2022-09-14 11:00:00 |
|  5 | 2022-09-14 12:00:00 |
|  6 | 2022-09-14 13:00:00 |
|  7 | 2022-09-14 14:00:00 |
|  8 | 2022-09-14 15:00:00 |
|  9 | 2022-09-14 16:00:00 |
| 10 | 2022-09-14 17:00:00 |
| 11 | 2022-09-14 18:00:00 |
| 12 | 2022-09-14 19:00:00 |
| 13 | 2022-09-15 08:00:00 |
| 14 | 2022-09-15 09:00:00 |
| 15 | 2022-09-15 10:00:00 |
| 16 | 2022-09-15 11:00:00 |
| 17 | 2022-09-15 12:00:00 |
| 18 | 2022-09-15 13:00:00 |
| 19 | 2022-09-15 14:00:00 |
| 20 | 2022-09-15 15:00:00 |
```

In this example, the index works! It's a simple `select id, date from activities`
Something strange happens when I use date ranges:
a) In this case (using a "daily" range) the index works:

```
select 
a.date
a.id,
a.address,
a.title,
a.state
    from activities a
where a.date >= "2022-09-14 00:00" and a.date <= "2022-09-14 23:59"
and exists ( select worker_id from worker_to_activity where worker_id = "worker_id" and activity_id = a.id ) 
limit 11;
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2022-09-14 08:00:00 |
|  2 | 2022-09-14 09:00:00 |
|  3 | 2022-09-14 10:00:00 |
| 50 | 2022-09-14 10:55:49 |
|  4 | 2022-09-14 11:00:00 |
|  5 | 2022-09-14 12:00:00 |
|  6 | 2022-09-14 13:00:00 |
|  7 | 2022-09-14 14:00:00 |
|  8 | 2022-09-14 15:00:00 |
|  9 | 2022-09-14 16:00:00 |
| 10 | 2022-09-14 17:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

b) When I use a wider range, i.e the activities in the next two days, the index "stops working (?)":

```
select 
a.date
a.id,
a.address,
a.title,
a.state
    from activities a
where a.date >= "2022-09-14 00:00" and a.date <= "2022-09-15 23:59"
and exists ( select worker_id from worker_to_activity where worker_id = "worker_id" and activity_id = a.id ) 
limit 11;
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2022-09-14 08:00:00 |
|  2 | 2022-09-14 09:00:00 |
|  3 | 2022-09-14 10:00:00 |
|  4 | 2022-09-14 11:00:00 |
|  5 | 2022-09-14 12:00:00 |
|  6 | 2022-09-14 13:00:00 |
|  7 | 2022-09-14 14:00:00 |
|  8 | 2022-09-14 15:00:00 |
|  9 | 2022-09-14 16:00:00 |
| 10 | 2022-09-14 17:00:00 |
| 11 | 2022-09-14 18:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

The `EXPLAIN` of both queries is slightly different, but I don't understand what causes this behaviour:
a) `EXPLAIN` a:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type   | possible_keys              | key           | key_len | ref                   | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a                  | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,date,act_fetch_idx | act_fetch_idx | 4       | NULL                  |   13 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | worker_to_activity | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,worker_id          | PRIMARY       | 522     |         db.a.id,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

b) `EXPLAIN` b:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type   | possible_keys                               | key       | key_len | ref                                       | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | worker_to_activity | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,worker_id                           | worker_id | 514     | const                                     |   23 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a                  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,date,act_fetch_idx,count_activities | PRIMARY   | 8       |         db.worker_to_activity.activity_id |    1 |    53.49 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

The naive solution is using `ORDER BY` (which produces the same result as the first scenario both in execution plan and results), but my question was more about **why** this happens: shouldn't the index sort the results in both cases? I searched on the web but I couldn't find much.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those EXPLAINs are quite different.

The first query noticed that the date range was "small" so it decided to start with `activities`, fetch a few rows, check each against the other table.

The second query decided that the other table might be a better starting point.

(Caveat:  Since the Optimizer has no cross-table statistics, there is a non-trivial chance that it will pick the 'wrong' order to look at the two tables.)

It is usually "wrong" to use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.  Since the query plans produced the rows in different ways, you should expect the 11 rows to be different and sorted differently.

You could experiment further by using `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` -- this gives some more clues into the Optimizer's thinking.  For even more clues, see "Optimizer trace".  And I like checking the `Handler` counts:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight! Using LIMIT without ORDER BY is unsafe because it simply doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: @EmilianoMaccaferri - Yes.  The Optimizer is free to give you _any_ 11 rows.  I use it to get a quick sample of rows, but otherwise, it does not make sense.